# MockWebServer throwing java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, retrofit2, mockwebserver

I'm following the code here: [Android Unit Test with Retrofit2 and Mockito or Robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748656/android-unit-test-with-retrofit2-and-mockito-or-robolectric)

and I'm trying to run this code:

```
mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("your json body"));

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("").toString())
                //TODO Add your Retrofit parameters here
                .build();
```

but at the build() method it throws :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 


java.lang.AssertionError
    at okhttp3.internal.AndroidPlatform.isCleartextTrafficPermitted(AndroidPlatform.java:143)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:73)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.build(Retrofit.java:551)
    at com.test.mc.ia.UnitTests.testGetUsers(UnitTests.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:245)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:171)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:137)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
```

and I can't figure out why

Comment: Can you put all the logs from t he stacktrance?

Comment: @ Rod_Algonquin  added stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Ah figured it out. It was Robolectric:

changed:

@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = JELLYBEAN, packageName = "com.test.mc.instagram")

TO

@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 23, packageName = "com.test.mc.instagram")

see this:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2591